# How do I set up Netgear wireless connection in Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

I have an ethernet connection to get on the internet but my building is all WiFI. I have a desktop PC that is wired. I dont have a router. I have only a Linux O.S. and no windows. It was installed when I got the machine. I want to use only the wireless connection. I have a Netgear adaptor WNA1100 and I am in Linux Ubuntu version 12.04. What packages do I install or what drivers do I need? AT&T sent me a CD with windows files that wont work.

I had version 10.04 but was told it was too old for the adaptor so I just upgraded to 12.04 and cant find anything but will try. I havent found the Synaptic Pkg Manager yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds weard. Do you have your ethernet drivers functioning? if yes, check this:
[On linux forms](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/wireless-internet/173652-solved-netgear-wna1100-ubuntu-10-10-a.html)

...btw: for synaptic, open a terminal (menu.accesories) and type:

> sudo apt-get install synaptic -y

after that it will apear in your apps menu. Or simply type in a terminal

> synaptic &

Comment: Whats weird. How do I establish a wireless connection?